# 'Create VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following SQL:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_gettasks]  
    @ID varchar(50)

    AS
     declare @PDate Date


     WHILE (DATEPART(DW, @PDate) =  1 OR DATEPART(DW, @PDate) =  7 )
     BEGIN

      set @PDate =  DATEADD(day, 1, @PDate)

     END

     CREATE VIEW tblList AS

     select tt.ItemOrder,tt.DisplayVal,  DATEADD(day, tt.DaysDue, @PDate)  from tblLine tt
     where tt.ID = 1
```

I get the following message:

> Incorrect syntax: 'Create VIEW' must be the only statement in the batch

I tried putting `GO` before `Create View`, but then it can't recognize the value of `PDate`.

Comment: Why are you creating views in a stored procedure?

Comment: @AaronBertrand doesn't necessarily have to be in a stored procedure. You get the same error if you have a database project with creation scripts where you attempt to put the Create View statement in an IF statement to only create it if it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Jacques That wasn't the point of my question, though. I wasn't suggesting the error was because it was happening in a procedure. I was curious why they were doing that in the first place (never mind the error).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create a view in a stored procedure, you need to do this in dynamic SQL (especially since the view itself can't take a variable). This is because modules can not be created as part of a larger script (like one that would be required if you have conditional logic, like `IF <some condition> CREATE VIEW`).

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'CREATE VIEW dbo.tblList 
    AS
      SELECT ItemOrder, DisplayVal, 
        SomeAlias = DATEADD(DAY, DaysDue, ''' 
          + CONVERT(char(8), @PDate, 112)
          + N''') FROM dbo.tblLine WHERE ID = 1;';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
```

But once you call this stored procedure a second time, it's going to fail, because you are trying to create a view named `dbo.tblList` and that view already exists. Perhaps you can elaborate on what you're trying to, at a higher level than "I want to create a view in a stored procedure."

Of course, in modern versions, you can just say:

```
CREATE OR ALTER VIEW ...
```

...and not have to worry about whether or not it already exists (you just have to worry if you're *accidentally* replacing a very different view that happens to have the same name).

Comment: He could avoid creation by saying "IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.columns WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tblList') BEGIN CREATE VIEW ... END". I'm trying to do this, but I get the same error What @NatePet quotes. I srsly need to put the whole statement into a string? Why does ALTER VIEW behave like that?